# Splitting dataset to 90,10 instead of n_folds

Tags: python, pandas, random, dataset, random-forest

I use the randomforest algorithm. I would like to use the following code. Instead of evaluating the algorithm through n_folds, I would like to split it into 90% for train and 10% for test.
I changed the `n_folds` into `n_folds=1` and added the following lines:

```
train, test = train_test_split(dataset1, test_size=0.1, random_state = 0) ###<-----
df = dataset1.astype('str')
dataset = df.values.tolist()

train1 = train.astype('str')
train = train1.values.tolist()

test1 = test.astype('str')
test = test1.values.tolist()
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GX.py", line 266, in <module>
    scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, random_forest, n_folds, max_depth, min_size, sample_size, n_trees, n_features)
  File "GX.py", line 92, in evaluate_algorithm
    predicted = algorithm(train_set, test_set, *args)
  File "GX.py", line 223, in random_forest
    tree = build_tree(sample, max_depth, min_size, n_features)
  File "GX.py", line 183, in build_tree
    root = get_split(train, n_features)
  File "GX.py", line 137, in get_split
    index = randrange(len(dataset[0]) - 1)
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

```
# Select the best split point for a dataset
def get_split(dataset, n_features):
    class_values = list(set(row[-1] for row in dataset))
    b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = 999, 999, 999, None
    features = list()
    while len(features) < n_features:
        index = randrange(len(dataset[0])-1)
        if index not in features:
            features.append(index)
    for index in features:
        for row in dataset:
            groups = test_split(index, row[index], dataset)
            gini = gini_index(groups, class_values)
            if gini < b_score:
                b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = index, row[index], gini, groups
    return {'index':b_index, 'value':b_value, 'groups':b_groups}


# Random Forest Algorithm on Sonar Dataset
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from csv import reader
from math import sqrt


# Load a CSV file
def load_csv(filename):
    dataset = list()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not row:
                continue
            dataset.append(row)
    return dataset


# Convert string column to float
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())


# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(dataset, column):
    class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
    unique = set(class_values)
    lookup = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup


# Split a dataset into k folds
def cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds):
    dataset_split = list()
    dataset_copy = list(dataset)
    fold_size = int(len(dataset) / n_folds)
    for i in range(n_folds):
        fold = list()
        while len(fold) < fold_size:
            index = randrange(len(dataset_copy))
            fold.append(dataset_copy.pop(index))
        dataset_split.append(fold)
    return dataset_split


# Calculate accuracy percentage
def accuracy_metric(actual, predicted):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(actual)):
        if actual[i] == predicted[i]:
            correct += 1
    return correct / float(len(actual)) * 100.0


# Evaluate an algorithm using a cross validation split
def evaluate_algorithm(dataset, algorithm, n_folds, *args):
    folds = cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds)
    scores = list()
    for fold in folds:
        train_set = list(folds)
        train_set.remove(fold)
        train_set = sum(train_set, [])
        test_set = list()
        for row in fold:
            row_copy = list(row)
            test_set.append(row_copy)
            row_copy[-1] = None
        predicted = algorithm(train_set, test_set, *args)
        actual = [row[-1] for row in fold]
        accuracy = accuracy_metric(actual, predicted)
        scores.append(accuracy)
    return scores


# Split a dataset based on an attribute and an attribute value
def test_split(index, value, dataset):
    left, right = list(), list()
    for row in dataset:
        if row[index] < value:
            left.append(row)
        else:
            right.append(row)
    return left, right


# Calculate the Gini index for a split dataset
def gini_index(groups, classes):
    # count all samples at split point
    n_instances = float(sum([len(group) for group in groups]))
    # sum weighted Gini index for each group
    gini = 0.0
    for group in groups:
        size = float(len(group))
        # avoid divide by zero
        if size == 0:
            continue
        score = 0.0
        # score the group based on the score for each class
        for class_val in classes:
            p = [row[-1] for row in group].count(class_val) / size
            score += p * p
        # weight the group score by its relative size
        gini += (1.0 - score) * (size / n_instances)
    return gini


# Select the best split point for a dataset
def get_split(dataset, n_features):
    class_values = list(set(row[-1] for row in dataset))
    b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = 999, 999, 999, None
    features = list()
    while len(features) < n_features:
        index = randrange(len(dataset[0]) - 1)
        if index not in features:
            features.append(index)
    for index in features:
        for row in dataset:
            groups = test_split(index, row[index], dataset)
            gini = gini_index(groups, class_values)
            if gini < b_score:
                b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = index, row[index], gini, groups
    return {'index': b_index, 'value': b_value, 'groups': b_groups}


# Create a terminal node value
def to_terminal(group):
    outcomes = [row[-1] for row in group]
    return max(set(outcomes), key=outcomes.count)


# Create child splits for a node or make terminal
def split(node, max_depth, min_size, n_features, depth):
    left, right = node['groups']
    del (node['groups'])
    # check for a no split
    if not left or not right:
        node['left'] = node['right'] = to_terminal(left + right)
        return
    # check for max depth
    if depth >= max_depth:
        node['left'], node['right'] = to_terminal(left), to_terminal(right)
        return
    # process left child
    if len(left) <= min_size:
        node['left'] = to_terminal(left)
    else:
        node['left'] = get_split(left, n_features)
        split(node['left'], max_depth, min_size, n_features, depth + 1)
    # process right child
    if len(right) <= min_size:
        node['right'] = to_terminal(right)
    else:
        node['right'] = get_split(right, n_features)
        split(node['right'], max_depth, min_size, n_features, depth + 1)


# Build a decision tree
def build_tree(train, max_depth, min_size, n_features):
    root = get_split(train, n_features)
    split(root, max_depth, min_size, n_features, 1)
    return root


# Make a prediction with a decision tree
def predict(node, row):
    if row[node['index']] < node['value']:
        if isinstance(node['left'], dict):
            return predict(node['left'], row)
        else:
            return node['left']
    else:
        if isinstance(node['right'], dict):
            return predict(node['right'], row)
        else:
            return node['right']


# Create a random subsample from the dataset with replacement
def subsample(dataset, ratio):
    sample = list()
    n_sample = round(len(dataset) * ratio)
    while len(sample) < n_sample:
        index = randrange(len(dataset))
        sample.append(dataset[index])
    return sample


# Make a prediction with a list of bagged trees
def bagging_predict(trees, row):
    predictions = [predict(tree, row) for tree in trees]
    return max(set(predictions), key=predictions.count)


# Random Forest Algorithm
def random_forest(train, test, max_depth, min_size, sample_size, n_trees, n_features):
    trees = list()
    for i in range(n_trees):
        sample = subsample(train, sample_size)
        tree = build_tree(sample, max_depth, min_size, n_features)
        trees.append(tree)
    predictions = [bagging_predict(trees, row) for row in test]
    return (predictions)

seed(1)
import pandas as pd
file_path ='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data'
dataset2 = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=',')

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset2)
dataset1 = dataset1.drop(0, axis=1)

train, test = train_test_split(dataset1, test_size=0.1, random_state = 0) ###<-----
df = dataset1.astype('str')
dataset = df.values.tolist()

train1 = train.astype('str')
train = train1.values.tolist()

test1 = test.astype('str')
test = test1.values.tolist()

target_index = 0 ##<----
for i in range(0, len(dataset[0])):
        if i != target_index:
            str_column_to_float(dataset, i)
# convert class column to integers
str_column_to_int(dataset, target_index)

# evaluate algorithm
n_folds = 1
max_depth = 10
min_size = 1
sample_size = 1.0
n_features = int(sqrt(len(dataset[0]) - 1))


for n_trees in [5]:
    scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, random_forest, n_folds, max_depth, min_size, sample_size, n_trees, n_features)
    print('Trees: %d' % n_trees)
    print('Scores: %s' % scores)
    print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f%%' % (sum(scores) / float(len(scores))))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you doing n_folds validation it automatically loops over folds and trains a model on n-1 fold.
For example if you split it into 4 folds 25% each (a, b, c, d) it will
 train on (a, b, c) and test on (d)
train on (a, b, d) and test on (c)
train on (a, c, d) and test on (b)
train on (b, c, d) and test on (a)
then it takes average error.
In that case, if you make 10 folds it will train on 90% of data 10 times.
But if you don't want to use folds at all, just use train_test_split alone.
Consider following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100)
features = ['f_{}'.format(i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=features)
df['target'] = y

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[features].values, 
    df['target'].values, 
    test_size=0.1,
    stratify=df['target'],
    random_state=42
)

print('X_train:', X_train.shape, 'y_train:', y_train.shape,)
print('X_test:', X_test.shape, 'y_test:', y_test.shape,)
```

output:

```
X_train: (90, 20) y_train: (90,)
X_test: (10, 20) y_test: (10,)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexOzerov, This is the type of code I need. How can I insert it to my original code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [LeavePOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeavePOut.html#sklearn.model_selection.LeavePOut), which allows you to select a certain number of items out of the training for validation. You just need to work out how many you need to leave out for it to be 10% of the sample.

Comment: Thanks @Jblasco, I need to change the code so that instead of n_folds will train the 90% and test it over the 10%. My split do the work, however I get errors.